# How to send message to Slack every 'x' number of hours?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, slack

I have a configuration page where the user can select at what time to receive certain information from my API, for example they could select to get the information every day at 5PM or every Friday at 5PM. After this is set, the user should receive a Slack message at the time they defined, for example, every day at 5PM they would receive a message...

I save the user's timezone so that I can send the message to them in Slack at the correct time for them.

That being said, how can I schedule this message to send out from my node.js app? I would have a few users in the system, all who would have likely chosen different times so I would need a timer per user?

The only thing I can think of is scanning all users in the system, getting their selected time and then sending the message to them...but this doesn't seem scalable.

I'm not looking for a complete solution for this, just some pointers for how to design this sort of functionality.

I also looked into Slack scheduled messages but this isn't exactly what I'm looking for. Note: I can already send messages to Slack, I'm more interested in how to build the timer mechanism.

Thanks in advance!

### EDIT:

Did a bit more research and it looks like node-schedule could be an option to schedule jobs: https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule#readme

With using this package, is the approach that I scan all users in my database at let's say midnight everyday and schedule jobs based on their settings...then those jobs execute at their scheduled time and the user receives the message in Slack. Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the core logic I would suggest something like this:

- Store the timing of delivery (e.g. 5 AM ever Friday) for every user in your database
- Then have a worker process that is running on a regular basis, e.g.
  every 5 minutes
- When it runs it checks if there are any due messages to be delivered
- If yes it sends the message with your API information to the user and store the last time of sending for the user

This approach is resilient to downtime. It will just resume sending due messages once the worker process is running again after a downtime.

It is also scaleable: If needed you can run multiple worker processes (make sure to design your workers to support concurrent processing, e.g. with transactions)

Some additional things to consider:

- Would limit the number of messages sent per run to avoid timeouts and having too many workers running in parallel
- You need some error handling if sending message to Slack fails
- To avoid timezone complexities I would suggest to convert all timings to UTC for processing in your app

Comment: Thank you for the input! I went with a very similar approach based on this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a regular task? In other words, it's executed every day at the same time for user X? If so, `node-schedule` seems fine, and it can run the same job regularly, you just have to set it up properly via a cron-like string (see the instructions in the README). If a user changes their setting, you then modify the previous job. The downside with `node-schedule` is that you need to set it up everytime your application is loaded, which can take a while and consume lots of resources if you have too many users.

Alternatively, if the number of users is big or you prefer to keep your application stateless, you can set a number of slots for sending these messages (and run that in a separate process from your main application). Let's say, a slot every 30 min. Then you set timers for those time slots (using `node-schedule` if you like, it will be just 48 timers), fetch the list of users for that time slot from the database, and send the messages.

Overall, NodeJS/JavaScript is pretty efficient with this sort of timer-based scheduling. If you want an in-depth dive into the reasons, see this: https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

You also need to consider what happens in case your application suffers from downtime. Should users be guaranteed to receive those messages, even if they are late? But that's another story :-)